# TestNG: Go to the next test after one iteration of dataProvider

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

So I have two tests, one that check the sign up "test01_signIn", if it's a PASS, it goes to the the second test "test02_CheckNewsStandElements", which checks the visibility of an element of the homepage. The only issue is that the first test has a DataProvider like the following:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "Data")
public void test01_signIn(String idMedia, String nomMedia, String idSSO, String mdpSSO, String lien) 
{
    //Test
}

@Test
public void test02_CheckNewsStandElements() 
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
    WebElement modalCloseButton = null;
    modalCloseButton = nsp.modalCloseButton(driver);
    try
    {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(modalCloseButton));
    }catch(TimeoutException e){
        System.out.println("The Element isn't visible");
    }
}

@DataProvider(name="Data")
public Object [][] getLists() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException 
{
    Object [][] objects = newEDLI.importData().clone();
    return objects;
}
```

The results I get are more like: 
Test1
Test1
Test1
...
Test2.
(only one iteration of Test2)

While I'm looking for a result like this:
Test1
Test2
Test1
Test2

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with **@Factory** annotation and **group-by-instances** parameter in TestNG;

```
@Factory(dataProvider="dp")
public Object[] createDataProviderInstances(int id) {
    return new Object[] {new TestClass(id)};
}
```

And in the testng xml file;

```
< !DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="LocalSuite" verbose="1">
    <test name="NameOfTest" group-by-instances="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="package.name.TestClass"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Find the detailed example in [here](https://dzone.com/articles/testng-run-tests-sequentially)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i have one issue with it, it keeps opening multiple chrome windows for each test, i have 170 lines in my data sheet, which means 170 window, this will cook my pc, is there a way i can open them in the same window ?

Comment: Why do you run same test01_signIn() for each test02_CheckNewsStandElements()? Are the signed in credentials different in each test?  
  
Chrome driver intitated for each test in data sheet means; driver inititation is done inside the test01_signIn().  
  
**To run all tests in a single browser instance;  **
1. Remove driver inititation from the test01_signIn() and put inside a new method. Add BeforeSuite annotation to it.  
2. Then create a sign out method and add AfterClass annotation